# Tiled - Possible to create a terrain from this specific tileset?

Tags: tiles, tilemap, tiled

I'm really new to Tiled and I can't get the hang of creating terrains.

I have these really nice 2D assets I would like to use but I can't get the terrains to work. I'm trying to create a dirt path terrain brush from the below tileset.

I've checked countless tutorials but nothing works. I'm starting to think these just aren't compatible with Tiled.

Could someone tell me if it's meant to be possible?

I've added a watermark to the tile image below as these are commercial assets.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I am using very similar tilesets in tiled, and they surely are compatible. Maybe you explain more what you try to du und where the problem is?
I made a PoC some time ago, the result looked like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TImh7ODK_fc
made with Tiled and a tileset like yours.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like this tileset will be usable with the [Tiled terrain tool](http://doc.mapeditor.org/en/latest/manual/using-the-terrain-tool/) without some modifications. For example there are three pieces at the top and bottom of the dirt and sand patches that need to be used together, whereas the terrain tool expects there to be one or more tiles that are interchangeable at the sides of such patches.

You could try to use [automapping rules](http://doc.mapeditor.org/en/latest/manual/automapping/) if you want to automate these transitions to their full potential.